# Calling a method within Portlet when submitting form

Tags: php, yii

I have a Portlet that contains a form. Now what I want to achieve is the following.

1) A Porlet containing a form is called within a page via

```
<?php $this->widget('form'); ?>
```

2) The user fills in this form and clicks on submit "The submit button should be an ajax button"
3) When submit has been pressed the form should call a method within the form portlet class and the form should be replaced with a Thank you message.
4) I only want the current view in the portlet replaced with another view.

My portlet class looks like this

```
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CPortlet');

class Polls extends CPortlet{

    public $usr_id=''; 


    public function init(){

        $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
        $cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');
        parent::init();
    }

    protected function renderContent(){    
        $this->render('form');
    }

    public function update(){
       $this->render('thankyou');
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do it with portlet only since portlet itself can't be reached via URL. You have to create a proxy controller action like this:

```
ProxyController extends CController {
  function actionPortlet(){
    $portlet = new Polls();
    $portlet->usr_id = 123;
    $portlet->update();
  }
}
```